# Laravel 6.x - Cannot update form in Controller method(Nested-Child)

Tags: php, laravel, nested, laragon

Im new in Laravel. Currently im facing a problem where I am stuck in the middle of **updating details from all child** but was fine in updating parent's details. So here i'll show one of the child which is Staff(Process as Parent)

#### 1) StaffController.php (Update Method)

```
public function update($processes_id, Request $request, Staff $staff)
{
    // $staff->update($request->all());
    // return redirect()->route('processes.staffs.index', $processes_id);

    $request->validate([
        'staffName' => 'required',
        'staffDept' => 'required',
        'staffSection' => 'required',
        ]);

    $staff->update($request->all());
    // $staff = Process::find($id);

    // $staff->staffName = $request->input('staffName');
    // $staff->staffDept = $request->input('staffDept');
    // $staff->staffSection = $request->input('staffSection');
    // $process->save();

    return redirect()->route('processes.staffs.index')
                     ->with('success','Asset updated successfully.');
}
```

I've tried the commented code, still **no changes** were made when enter new details.

#### 2) edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Edit Staff</h1>

    <!-- FORM -->
    {{-- {!! Form::open(['action' => ['ProcessesController@update', [$staff->id, $staff->processes_id]], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('staffName', 'staffName:')}}
            {{Form::text('staffName', $staff->staffName, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('staffDept', 'staffDept:')}}
            {{Form::text('staffDept', $staff->staffDept, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('staffSection', 'staffSection:')}}
            {{Form::text('staffSection', $staff->staffSection, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
        </div>

        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        <a href="/processes" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
    </div>

    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}

    {!! Form::close() !!} --}}

    <form action="{{ route('processes.staffs.update', [$staff->processes_id, $staff->id]) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
   
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Staff Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $staff->staffName }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Staff Department:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $staff->staffDept }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Staff Section:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $staff->staffSection }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-left">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              <a href="/processes" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Also tried the commented form above, it gave me **Array to Conversion Error**.

#### 3) index.blade.php(Edit link is in this blade file)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Staffs</h1>
    @if(count($staffs) > 0)
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th width="280px">Action</th>
            </tr>

            @php $i = 0 @endphp
            
            @foreach ($staffs as $staff)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                <td>{{ $staff->staffName }}</td>
                <td>{{ $staff->staffDept }}</td>
                <td>{{ $staff->staffSection }}</td>
                
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('processes.staffs.show',[$staff->processes_id, $staff->id]) }}">Show</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('processes.staffs.edit',[$staff->processes_id, $staff->id]) }}">Edit</a>
       
                    @csrf
                    {{-- @method('DELETE')
          
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> --}}
                    <form action="{{ route('processes.staffs.destroy', [$staff->processes_id, $staff->id]) }}" method="POST">
                           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>

        {{-- {{$staffs->links()}} --}}
    @else
        <p>No staffs found!</p>
    @endif
    <a href="{{ route("processes.staffs.create", $processes_id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Staff</a>
    <a href="/processes" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
@endsection
```

#### 4) web.php(Route file)

```
//Asset
Route::resource('processes','ProcessesController');

// Staff
Route::resource('processes.staffs','StaffController');
Route::PUT('/processes/{process}/staffs/{staff}','StaffController@update');
```

Any suggestion and answer are much welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: what is `$processes_id` for ?

Comment: that one is for passing primary key of parent(process) to the child(staff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution from my friend, which is the silly mistake in the **edit.blade.php** update form.

the (name="name") supposed to changed according to its variable name in database table

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $staff->staffName }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
```

So, below is the correct one:

```
<input type="text" name="staffName" value="{{ $staff->staffName }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
```

Thanks for now, it works and can update the details.